# How to change color of placeholder in javascript format?

Tags: javascript, placeholder

How do I change the color of the placeholder to white? I know I have to use the -moz-placeholder but I don't know how to format it into JAVASCRIPT. I need to to match the code I have below in the format of javascript.

```
           //User Name Input
            var inputUserName = document.createElement("input");
            inputUserName.type = "text";
            inputUserName.style.bottom = "220px";
            inputUserName.style.width = "170px";
            inputUserName.style.height = "20px";
            inputUserName.style.left = "50px";
            inputUserName.style.textAlign = "center";
            inputUserName.style.display = "none";
            inputUserName.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
            inputUserName.style.borderBottom = "2px solid black";
            inputUserName.style.borderTop = "transparent";
            inputUserName.style.borderLeft = "transparent";
            inputUserName.style.borderRight = "transparent";
            inputUserName.placeholder = "User Name";
            inputUserName.style.color = "white";
            inputUserName.style.position = "absolute";
            inputUserName.className = "UserNameSignUp";
            inputUserName.UserNameSignUp = "-moz-placeholder";
        //input.className = "css-class-name"; // set the CSS class
        formArea.appendChild(inputUserName); // put it into the DOM
```

Answer (score 0):

**-moz-placeholder** is a pseudo class and therefore is not directly part of the DOM, so you can't edit it the same way or add inline style to it.

A workaround would be changing the stylesheet dynamically like

```
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('#xyz:-moz-placeholder { background-color: white; }', 0);
```

considering it has some id("#xyz").

Refer to this documentation for reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule